# Does unbounded curvature implies unbounded diameter?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold. Assume that for each $C > 0$ there exists $p\in M$ and $X,Y\in T_pM$ unitary such that $K(X,Y) > C$. Does this implies that the diameter of $M$ is infinite?

I just have an intuition about it, related to the this figure:[Gabriel's  Horn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel%27s_Horn)

Comment: Firstly, Gabriel's Horn has negative curvature. There are many results connecting sectional and Ricci curvature to diameter.

Comment: you are right about Gabriel's horn, but can you point out some theorem relating the upper bound for sectional curvature and diameter?

Comment: There's the Bonnet-Myers theorem.

Comment: Assuming completeness, yes. If the diameter is finite the manifold is compact. The curvature tensor is smooth, hence continuous, hence its norm is uniformly bounded.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a sequence of rapidly shrinking spheres all stitched to the same finite open section of a plane. Here, the manifold is not complete though.